# JTable - How to force user to select exactly one row

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have to implement a JTable in which exactly one row has to be selected (always). Empty selection is not allowed. I'm selecting the first row during initialization:

```
table.setRowSelectionInterval(0, 0);
```

additionally, I'm using

```
table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
```

But user can still deselect one row using CLick + Ctrl.

What is the easiest way ensure, that one (exaclty) row is always selected in the table ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Now, you could add `MouseListener`s, `SelectionListener`s, `KeyListener`s and key bindings to try and solve this is issue.  Or, you could go to the heart of the problem.

The `ListSelectionModel` is responsible for managing the selection details.

You could simply supply your own `ListSelectionModel` for the row selection

```
public class ForcedListSelectionModel extends DefaultListSelectionModel {

    public ForcedListSelectionModel () {
        setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    }

    @Override
    public void clearSelection() {
    }

    @Override
    public void removeSelectionInterval(int index0, int index1) {
    }

}
```

And simply set it to your table...

```
table.setSelectionModel(new ForcedListSelectionModel());
```

Comment: This answer is unnecessarily complex, see the single-line answer below it!

Comment: @SomeDude In my experience, that doesn't always work as expected - also note *"Empty selection is not allowed"*

Answer (score 25):

If you have a JTable instance created, just use:

```
jTable1.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
```

Comment: Since this is what the OP is already doing and they stated "*But user can still deselect one row using CLick + Ctrl."* and they also stated *"Empty selection is not allowed"* - this won't be enough ... since this is what they are already doing

Answer (score 6):

> What is the easiest way ensure, that one (exaclty) row is always
>   selected in the table ?

there are three (basically) selection types

```
JTable.setRowSelectionAllowed(boolean);
JTable.setColumnSelectionAllowed(boolean);
JTable.setCellSelectionAllowed(boolean);
```

edit

works for me too

```
int row = table.getSelectedRow();
    if ((row > -1)) {
        table.setRowSelectionInterval(row, row);
    }
}
```

Comment: Personally, supplying a custom `ListSelectionModel` would be easier and avoid the need for a bunch of listeners that would probably contradict each other - IMHO

Comment: interesting +1, but code from my edit is from ListSelectionListener with setCellSelectionAllowed

Comment: I'm not saying its wrong (to use a ListSelectionListener), but you start running into the problem of "did I just make the change or I'm begin notified of, or is it generated by something else?" and end up with all these fun flags and stuff which could simply avoided - IMHO

Answer (score 1):

I would use the [JTable#setRowSelectionAllowed](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setRowSelectionAllowed%28boolean%29) as it will ensure that a row can be selected.

Answer (score 0):

This code changes it right back to the desired index and it gives the appearance to the user that it never updates.

```
table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(
    new ListSelectionListener() {
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
            table.setRowSelectionInterval(0,0);
        }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

First do

```
table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
table.setRowSelectionInterval(0, 0);
```

then set `ListSelectionModel`